# The Number of Two-digit Primes Which the Sum of their Digits is 6

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, problem-solving

> *Problem:* Find the number of two-digit primes which the sum of their digits is six.

We had this problem in a mathematic examination. The problem can be solved by testing all two-digit primes, but I wish a more mathematical solution.

Comment: Hint: $5+1=6$, $2+4=6$ and $3+3=6$ Thus, there are very few cases to test.

Comment: A number whose digits add to a multiple of three is a multiple of three.

Comment: There are $0$ primes which have sum as multiple of $3$ as primes have only $2$ multiples $1$,themselves

Comment: Trick question. Any number shows digital sum is 6 is divisible by 3 and is not prime !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that a number whose sum of digits is divisible by 3 is divisible by 3. Since we argue about 2 digit numbers, every such number whose digits add up to 6 is divisible by 3 and hence not a prime.

Comment: ... And $3$ is not a solution.

Comment: @StellaBiderman 3 isn't a 2 digit number.

Comment: Yes. The sum of the digits of &3$ is also not $5$. But $3$ is a prime that's divisible by three, so worth noting that it doesn't have the desired property

Comment: I mean $6$, not $5$